# Is a git fetch necessary before git subtree pull?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am in reference to the following article: [git subtree blog entry](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

Amongst other, the following commands are listed:

```
git remote add -f tpope-vim-surround https://bitbucket.org/vim-plugins-mirror/vim-surround.git
git subtree add --prefix .vim/bundle/tpope-vim-surround tpope-vim-surround master --squash
git fetch tpope-vim-surround master
git subtree pull --prefix .vim/bundle/tpope-vim-surround tpope-vim-surround master --squash
```

My question is:

> what is the need for the `git fetch tpope-vim-surround master`?
>   Is it not redundant with the git pull listed next line below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was fixed recently, but older versions of `git subtree` required a branch with the correct name to be present locally before it would fetch it remotely, or it would fail with "foo does not refer to a commit."

So it's probably for compatibility with that.

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` is actually an alias for 2 commands: `git fetch && git merge` so if you are running `git pull` you actually doing pull fetch as well.

> Is it not redundant with the git pull listed next line below?

#### What does fetch do?

In order to understand fetch let me explain a little bit what is going on beyhond the scenes in git.
Git store it content inside the `.git` folder. Lets look at it as the git internal file system.

When you execute `git fetch` its actually updating the internal git file system (to be more accurate the pack & index files). `fetch` **does not** update your working directory until you `merge` the changes to the desired branch

#### What deos git pull do?

As explained about `fetch`, `git pull` is actually an alias for 2 commands: `git fetch && git merge` so every time you do a `git pull` you are updating the git internal file system + merging those changes into the desired branch (in most cases your current branch)

---

So to answer your question:

> Is it not redundant with the git pull listed next line below?

the answer is that the first fetch is redundant and not the second pull.

Comment: This is a `git subtree pull` not `git pull`.